# Сгруппировать и посчитать значения в столбцах Python

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Есть данные в трех столбцах
[image: test]

на Python нужно сгруппировать данные по первой колонке, затем во второй колонке заменить все строки содержащие R на слово credit, а содержащие W на слово account и сложить их количество, но в пределах одного терминала по первой колонке.
Т.е. на терминале 1 было Х платежей на credit, и У платежей на account,  на терминале 2 было Z платежей на credit, и C платежей на account и так далее.

Comment: Анна, это звучит не как вопрос коллеги, который что-то сделал, но что-то не получилось и он просит помочь разобраться. Это звучит как ТЗ (техническое задание) программистам. Понятно, что тут есть ассы, которые могут это всё быстро закодить. Даже беспплатно. Но цель сообщества немножко другая. Попробуйте хотя бы псеводокодом и словами предложить свой алгоритм решения. И покажите где именно в этом алгоритме у вас что-то не получается. Спасибо. )

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .assign(account=df["account"]
                       .replace([r".*R.*", r".*W.*"], ["credit", "account"], 
               regex=True))
       .groupby(["term", "account"])
       .summ"]
       .sum())
```

**Ограничение ответственности:** решение не тестировалось, так как в вопросе не был приведен пример входных данных [в том виде, в котором я мог бы им воспользоваться](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060).